# Ошибка при выводе на экран таблицы используя вложенный цикл

Tags: python, python-3.x, table

Задача вывести на экран таблицу используя вложенный цикл:

```
print ("""
Name                 ID         Email               
--------------------------------------------------""")


data = [["Suresh Datta", 57394, "suresh@example.com"], ["Colette Browning", 48539, "colette@example.com"], ["Skye Homsi", 58302, "skye@example.com"], ["Hiroto Yamaguchi", 48502, "hiroto@example.com"], ["Tobias Ledford", 48291, "tobias@example.com"], ["Tamara Babic", 58201, "tamara@example.com"], ["Jin Xu", 48293, "jin@example.com"], ["Joana Dias", 23945, "joana@example.com"], ["Alton Derosa", 85823, "alton@example.com"]]

for row in data:
    for col in row:
        print ("%s \t %f \t %s" % (col, col,col, col,col, col,col, col,col, col,col, col,col, col,col, col,col, col,col, col,col, col,col, col))
```

Два вопроса:

1. Очевидно я как то криво перечислил параметр col в скобках. Как сократить правильно эту строчку?
2. У меня никак не выводится столбец с числами. Выпадает такая ошибка:

   > TypeError: must be real number, not str

Comment: кст, у вас опечатка в `data`: слишком много элементов в `["Tobias Ledford", 48291, "tobias@example.com"...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Советую ознакомиться с модулем [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html), предназначенным для быстрой обработки и визуализации табличных данных:

```
import pandas as pd    # pip install pandas

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name','ID','Email'])

print(df)
```

результат:

```
               Name     ID                Email
0      Suresh Datta  57394   suresh@example.com
1  Colette Browning  48539  colette@example.com
2        Skye Homsi  58302     skye@example.com
3  Hiroto Yamaguchi  48502   hiroto@example.com
4    Tobias Ledford  48291   tobias@example.com
5      Tamara Babic  58201   tamara@example.com
6            Jin Xu  48293      jin@example.com
7        Joana Dias  23945    joana@example.com
8      Alton Derosa  85823    alton@example.com
```

можно легко отсортировать или отфильтровать данные:

```
In [73]: print(df[df['Name'].str.contains(r'(?:Tamara|Joana)')].sort_values('ID'))
           Name     ID               Email
7    Joana Dias  23945   joana@example.com
5  Tamara Babic  58201  tamara@example.com
```

PS конечно для простого табличного вывода данного массива данных использование Pandas - это перебор, но Pandas открывает огромные возможности и, возможно, он вам пригодится для обработки, фильтрации, научных исследований, визуализации, etc.

---

**UPDATE:** слегка улучшенная версия форматирования от @gil9red:

```
In [89]: for row in data:
    ...:     print("{:>20} {:>10} {:>30}".format(*row))
    ...:
    ...:
        Suresh Datta      57394             suresh@example.com
    Colette Browning      48539            colette@example.com
          Skye Homsi      58302               skye@example.com
    Hiroto Yamaguchi      48502             hiroto@example.com
      Tobias Ledford      48291             tobias@example.com
        Tamara Babic      58201             tamara@example.com
              Jin Xu      48293                jin@example.com
          Joana Dias      23945              joana@example.com
        Alton Derosa      85823              alton@example.com
```

Comment: pandas для этого идеально подходит, но задача именно разобраться с форматированием представленным как у меня в коде.

Comment: @AntonZubochenko, добавил вариант обычного форматирования...

Comment: спасибо, а есть еще более олдскульный вариант со знаками процентов?

Comment: @AntonZubochenko, лучше сразу привыкать к правильному стилю форматирования ;)

Comment: дело в том, что делаю курс от майкрософт по пайтону и не понял зачем они это дают, потому что форма то архаичная немного.

Answer (score 5):

Исправил код в вопросе, таблица выводится:

```
print("""\
Name                 ID         Email               
--------------------------------------------------""")

for row in data:
    print("{} \t {} \t {}".format(*row))
```

---

Но я бы посоветовал использовать модуль [tabulate](https://bitbucket.org/astanin/python-tabulate/src/master/).

Удобный, простой, поддерживает разные стили таблицы (параметр `tablefmt`):

```
# pip install tabulate
from tabulate import tabulate
print(tabulate(data, headers=['Name', 'ID', 'Email'], tablefmt="grid"))
```

Результат:

```
+------------------+-------+---------------------+
| Name             |    ID | Email               |
+==================+=======+=====================+
| Suresh Datta     | 57394 | suresh@example.com  |
+------------------+-------+---------------------+
| Colette Browning | 48539 | colette@example.com |
+------------------+-------+---------------------+
| Skye Homsi       | 58302 | skye@example.com    |
+------------------+-------+---------------------+
| Hiroto Yamaguchi | 48502 | hiroto@example.com  |
+------------------+-------+---------------------+
| Tobias Ledford   | 48291 | tobias@example.com  |
+------------------+-------+---------------------+
| Tamara Babic     | 58201 | tamara@example.com  |
+------------------+-------+---------------------+
| Jin Xu           | 48293 | jin@example.com     |
+------------------+-------+---------------------+
| Joana Dias       | 23945 | joana@example.com   |
+------------------+-------+---------------------+
| Alton Derosa     | 85823 | alton@example.com   |
+------------------+-------+---------------------+
```